# Why atomic register have consensus number 1?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, atomic

I am reading `The Art of Multiprocessor Programming`. At chapter 5, it is difficult to me to understand why atomic register have consensus number 1.

Answer (score -1):

It is because once it reaches the critical section, it can only go one way univalent. To make it wait-free this rule has to be followed. But the contradiction is that the Thread A that read from an atomic register 2 times must have the same answer.